# Decode image from werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict received from POST request

Tags: python, c#, image, flask, post

I am attempting to send an image via an HTTP POST request in c# to be read by an API written in Python with Flask. On the c# frontend side, the code I am using to send the image is:

```cs
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://172.30.211.33:5000/post_data"), "POST", StringPhotoPath);
```

This code seems to work; on the API side I receive a message that data has been posted. The method I am using on the API side is as follows:

```py
@app.route('/post_data',methods=['POST'])
def post_data():
    global stored_data
    #maybe expand to other MIME types
    stored_data=request.files
    print('data posted')
    return "complete"
```

When I took a peek at the stored data after the upload this was the output:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: '9e6df298ff964b9c88df9f9634aa9e6d.jpg' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

This would be fine except that every attempt to read it results in

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How can I go about extracting an image object from this?

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you try to read it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution to this; you have to save the returned files to a temporary directory as the file storage object is indeed closed after the POST operation is completed with no way to open it. The code I used is as follows:

```py
global stored_filepath
file=request.files['file']
file.save('filepath'+file.filename)
#for later use
stored_filepath='C:\\Users\\rdp\\Documents\\GitHub\\Blueline-Python-Scripts\\production scripts\\data_files\\'+file.filename
```